# AfterTest can't work correctly?

Tags: testng

I am studying TestNG.  But I found in TestNG 6.8, Annotation AfterTest has problem.

@AfterTest: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods belonging to the classes inside the  tag have run.

it's from http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html.

but in fact, my test case has not been started, @AfterTest executed! why ? output like this.

```
beforeSuite!!!!!!!!
beforeTest!!!!!!!!
afterTest!!!!!!!!
PASSED: testContainEnglish
PASSED: testGetCurrency
PASSED: testGetCurrencyCode
PASSED: testGetCurrencyCodeAlt
PASSED: testGetNotNullValue
PASSED: testGetNotNullValue_hasDefaultValue
PASSED: testGetSplitListFromString
PASSED: testMappingTable

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

afterSuite!!!!!!!!

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Adding some code will surely help answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly. TestNG displays the all system.out strings from code and generates the result of each test only after them. To see it try to add the System.out string to each method with @Test annotation. And don't forget to set the value for verbose parametr 2 or more in the testng.xml. For example code:

```
@BeforeTest
    public void beforetest()
   {
        System.out.println("Before Test");
    }
@AfterTest
    public void aftertest()
{
        System.out.println("After Test");
    }
@Test
    public void test1()
{
        System.out.println("test1");
    }
@Test
    public void test2()
{
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
@Test
    public void test3()
{
        System.out.println("test3");
    }
```

and output info

```
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Before Test
test1
test2
test3
After Test
PASSED: test1
PASSED: test2
PASSED: test3
```